# how to find following derivative

Tags: derivatives

How to find $\frac{dy}{dx}$, where: $$ y=x^3 (1-\sec^{-1} (x))$$

This is my answer. is it right?

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =x^3 \frac{1}{x(x^2 -1)^{1/2}}  +3x^2 (1-\sec^{-1} (x))$$

Comment: please use Mathjax : https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: One previous similar question of yours was answered and there were mentioned options that allow you to check your results. Why make another post regarding a result check ?

Comment: what means $$\sec^{-1}(x)$$?

Comment: I am sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is close, you just are missing a minus sign:

By use of the product rule, the answer should be:
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2(1-sec^{-1}(x))-\frac{x^3}{x(x^2-1)^{1/2}}$$